# Distance between two points on OSM without routing information

Tags: openstreetmap, distance, distance-matrix

I need to find the distance between multiple points following roads on OSM.
I am aware of routing software like OSRM.
However, this is not a useful solution for me (at least the alternatives I've looked into) because these systems are too smart and take into account things like whether there are road restrictions on walking, whether u-turns are possible, etc. The effect is that I end up with a distance matrix that does not respect the triangle inequality.
I've tried tweaking the routing lua scripts for OSRM without success.

I am looking for something much dumber. Just the shortest path along any and all kinds of roads.

Perhaps it's possible to convert the OSM data to a graph and then find the distances that way? Are there ready-made tools for that? I found the cppRouting package in R, but no examples using OSM data.

Comment: I would try this with OSRM by using a profile that is allowed to use all types of ways and set the weight factor of each type to 1.

Comment: I tried this with all sorts of custom built profiles but still end up with this type of inequalities. It seems it's impossible to bypass things like roads that go in a single direction, which means the distances between A->B + C->B is shorter than A->C.

Comment: Does it also not work when replacing the distance for A->B and B->A by the minimum of A -> B and B -> A?

Comment: I tried several methods for fixing the resulting distance matrix, but it seems to be to broken. There appear to be too many small issues that add up.

Answer (score 1):

I would give a shot to https://pgrouting.org/docs/tools/osm2pgrouting.html

1. Download OSM data and import into postgis
2. Execute pgRouting routines.

Seems simpler, but I haven't tried it myself only read about it.

Answer (score 0):

If a Python approach would be acceptable for you, https://osmnx.readthedocs.io is probably the easiest solution.

You can find an example in the notebooks of the `osmnx-examples` repository: https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx-examples/blob/main/notebooks/02-routing-speed-time.ipynb